# Reading, understanding and fixing that code

Tags: java

```
public class Bug1 { 
   private String s;
   public void Bug1(){ 
    s = "hello"; 
   }
   public String toString() {
      return s;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bug1 x = new Bug1();
      System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Can someone please explain this code to me step by step, tell me why it's returning "null" from the out.print and then what needs to be changed so that it will return "hello" instead?

Comment: Step 1: Read a book. Step 2: do your homework Step 3: ... Step 4: Enjoy !

Comment: You have to leave out the `void` before `Bug1()` for it to be the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Java. The code in the `main` is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Bug1 x = new Bug1();
System.out.println(x);
```

}

So, you have created an object called `x` of type `Bug1`. I guess you read up on constructors. The line of code defined in the class:

```
public void Bug1(){ 
s = "hello"; 
}
```

You would expect this line of code to be a constructor. But alas, you made a small error. The definition of constructors states that constructors do not have a return type. Although, they do have the same name as the class. The part where to write `void Bug1()` causes it to be a function and not a constructor.

You should change your line of code to

```
public Bug1()
{
s="hello";
}
```

When you change it to this, you should have the result you are looking for. Try reading up on [Java Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). You obviously have grasped a few concepts and left with a few.

When printing an object, always use the [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method. This is useful method that will allow you to see the object in plaintext.

Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

As `public void Bug1()` is not a constructor it an API so on initializing Bug will call default constructor. By default value of String class is null.
Change `public void Bug1()` to `public Bug1()` to make it constructor

Answer (score 0):

The idea here was probably for `Bug1` (the method) to be a constructor. But for that to be the case, the signature needs to be `public Bug1()` (no `void`). As it stands, the line

```
  Bug1 x = new Bug1();  // create instance
```

Runs the default constructor instead, and `s` is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> and then what needs to be changed so that it will return "hello" instead?

change

```
public void Bug1(){
```

to

```
public Bug1(){
```

because it needs to be a constructor method. Constructor methods can't specify `void`.

and change

```
System.out.println(x);
```

to

```
System.out.println(x.toString());
```

because you need to call the method `toString()` on the instance of the class `Bug1` to get the return String.